# Calculated Column based on other table. Direct Query sql

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns

I have 2 tables sourced by direct query to sql.

Table1 contains 3 columns "Fruit", "Number", and "Date".

Table2 contains 2 columns "Country", and "Fruit".

Table2 is linked to Table1 with a 1->*(Many) link from Table2[Fruit] to Table1[Fruit].

I want to create a new column in Table2, containing the average of "Number" for a specified range of dates.

Any ideas of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Add a measure like `AverageNumber = SUM(Table1[Number])/COUNT(Table1[Date])`. The date range comes automatically from your filters/slicers, and the average will show correctly for a particular fruit due to the relationship you have added.